# Postgresql - 24 hour rolling window

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I am currently using Metabase to put together a live dashboard of some internal company metrics and one of the things I am trying to query is a 24 hour rolling window for transaction on our mobile app. Metabase has a useful visualization tool called "Smart Number" which allows you to compare changes in values over a defined time period. [Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soj0d.png)

I am having trouble writing a query that outputs data in 24 hour intervals so I can compare the past 24 hours to the 24 hours before that. I have tried using the date_trunc function to divide the transactions by hour and then possibly limit the results to the last 24 but it doesn't print out hours that don't have transactions.  I also tried using the filter function as seen in the code below but the data needs to to be transposed for "Smart Numbers" to work. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I should approach this problem?

Example of one of my approaches:

```
SELECT 

(DATE_TRUNC('hour', (reservations.created_at::timestamptz)))  as hour,
SUM(reservations.covers) as total_covers  

FROM reservations
JOIN restaurants on restaurants.id = reservations.restaurant_id

WHERE reservations.origin = 'mobile'
and restaurants.relationship_type in ('listing_only', 'difficult', 'ipad')

GROUP BY hour

ORDER BY hour desc
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
hour                       total_covers
"2019-02-19 15:00:00+00"    4
"2019-02-19 13:00:00+00"    15
"2019-02-19 12:00:00+00"    4
"2019-02-19 11:00:00+00"    4
"2019-02-19 10:00:00+00"    26
"2019-02-19 09:00:00+00"    5
"2019-02-19 08:00:00+00"    8
"2019-02-19 07:00:00+00"    12
"2019-02-19 03:00:00+00"    2
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
Time_Interval         Total_Covers
24 Hours                  389
48 Hours                  254
72 hours                  459
96 Hours                  239
```

Comment: I've edited the post to include that! Thanks :)

Comment: left join on a generate_series of dates. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 1):

This query uses the `date` function to group results.

```
SELECT 
  DATE(reservations.created_at) AS day,
  SUM(reservations.covers) AS total_covers
FROM reservations
WHERE 
  reservations.origin = 'mobile' AND 
  restaurants.relationship_type IN ('listing_only', 'difficult', 'ipad')
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC
```

This query calculates the total covers from the time of the query, and groups them by the number of days ago.

```
SELECT
  CEIL(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW() - reservations.created_at) / 86400) as days_ago
  SUM(reservations.covers) as total_covers,
FROM reservations
WHERE 
  reservations.origin = 'mobile' AND 
  restaurants.relationship_type IN ('listing_only', 'difficult', 'ipad')
GROUP BY days_ago
ORDER BY days_ago;
```

[See it in action on rextester](https://rextester.com/VSEKC39950).

Comment: Hey Richard! Thanks so much for your response. This query does work, the only problem is that its not outputting a rolling 24 hour window as much as it is outputting transactions per day. I am trying to get the past 24 hours compared to the 24 hours before that, even if the intervals span across 2 days. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a generated series for the `from`, and then left-joining the data you want to count. Idea being you want every hour to appear in the result, and every piece of data to be counted, but it is optional.

Note I just checked the query compiled; I don't have a mock schema on hand to test this.

```
SELECT 
hours.x as hour,
coalesce(SUM(reservations.covers), 0) as total_covers
FROM (
    select * from generate_series(date_trunc('hour', (now() - INTERVAL '24 hours')), now(), '1 hour')
) hours(x)
LEFT JOIN reservations on hours.x = (DATE_TRUNC('hour', (reservations.created_at::timestamptz)))
LEFT JOIN restaurants on restaurants.id = reservations.restaurant_id
WHERE reservations.origin = 'mobile'
and restaurants.relationship_type in ('listing_only', 'difficult', 'ipad')
GROUP BY hours.x
ORDER BY hours.x desc
```